# Read dynamic excel values using javascript and display in table

Tags: javascript, excel, npm, xlsx

I have an excel file where data changes every second and I want to read that data every second and update it in the web. I am thinking of creating a table and update it dynamically.

I am currently using xlsx node package to read the excel data.

```
//something like this, taken from stack itself
var XLSX = require('xlsx')
var workbook = XLSX.readFile('test.xlsx');
var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
var xlData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet_name_list[0]]);
console.log(xlData);
```

But once the values are changed it is not updated accordingly. I want the code read the changed values, so that I can update them in the web table.

Comment: `But once the values are changed it is not updated accordingly` Do you mean that some one change `test.xlsx` and you to hanble it ?

Comment: Yes. Stock market data is loaded in that excel, so every second data is updated

Comment: So, for update data you need to handle updating of this file and each time reload to your application

Comment: how do I achieve that?